# Identity Server 4 and User.Claims.Properties.Count always is 0 on client

Tags: identityserver4

I need to fill in the "Properties" in the client's claim.
I am writing down a claimon the IS4 server in the ProfileService class:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
 {
 // ...
 Claim claim = new Claim("userData", "personalRights");
    string valuePersonalRights = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRights);
    claim.Properties.Add(GetKeyValuePair("rights", valuePersonalRights));
    claims.Add(claim);

 context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
 }

private KeyValuePair<string, string> GetKeyValuePair(string key, string value)
{
   KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);

   return keyValuePair;
}
```

In this claim on the server there are records "Properties":
https://postgres-russia.ru/wp-content/files/is4_img/on_server.jpg

However, on the client, the properties of this claim are missing:
https://postgres-russia.ru/wp-content/files/is4_img/on_client.jpg

Client Configuration:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "mvc";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("domainGroups");
                    options.Scope.Add("geolocation");
                    options.Scope.Add("fullname");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name"
                    };
                });
```

How to get claims properties on the client?

Comment: Do you need authenticated user's claims, on your client? for e.g. what is user's name or email?

Comment: System.Security.Claims.Claim has the property IDictionary <string, string> System.Security.Claims.Claim.Properties.
I create a claim on the authentication server and put some information in System.Security.Claims.Claim.Properties. Properties counters in the identity server claim: 1.
When I get a set of claims on the client, this claim has a Properties counter of 0.
How to transfer the properties of the claim?

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining your client, you can assign it's claims too, which will be included in access token.

```
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new Client[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "spa",
                ClientName = "SPA Client",
                ClientUri = "",
                AllowedGrantTypes = {GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword,GrantType.ClientCredentials},
                RedirectUris =
                {
                },
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                // secret for authentication
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = { "","" },
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile","roles", IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName },
                Claims = new Claim[]//look at this property
                {
                    new Claim("prop1","value1")
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: claims.SelectMany(c=>c.Properties) no data on client

Comment: Would you share your code please. I couldn't understand your problem very good, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when using Net Core. For some reason, the Firefox browser was simply silent, without showing errors, and the Chrome browser pointed to 431 Request Header Fields Too Large. The size of the statements in the cookie was over 4096 byte. Solved by using the ITicketStore and storing the claims as claims in the user session. More details: stackoverrun.com/ru/q/11186809

More: [IIS Deployed ASP.NET Core application giving intermittent 431 Request headers too long error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307363/iis-deployed-asp-net-core-application-giving-intermittent-431-request-headers-to)